# Write a function that takes one row and returns a list of 2-dimension tuples: song title and points database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to preprocess some data so that I can start analyzing it. I currently have a data frame which contains data of Eurovision winners. I need to create a new data frame which contains the words from each of the songs, with the points of each song assigned to each word in a tuple. For example, if the song name is `'Hello World'` and the score is 31, I need to create two tuples `(Hello, 31)` and `(World, 31)` and add them to a list from which I can create a new data frame.

**Sample input**

[Here is the first row of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L2Zl.png).

**Sample Output**

The output I want from the first row is

```
[('Net', 31),('als', 31),('toen', 31)]
```

**Attempt**

```
def TupleGenerator(row):
    list =[]
    for item in ev['Song']: 
        tuple = (item, ev["Points"])
        list.append(tuple)
    return list
 

TupleGenerator(ev.iloc[0])
```

This is what I have tried so far, but I am not sure how to get the score from the same row to be assigned to the word in the tuple.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is an example of `row`? And what is your expected output?

Comment: row is a row in the data frame. I expect to create a list of two-dimensional tuples, with each containing 1 word from each song title and the points that song scored

Comment: We need to *see* a minimal example of such a row and the expected output. Please edit your post to include these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, only right now you are iterating over every character in the string `row["Song"]`. You need to split this string up into a sequence of substrings where each substring represents a word from the song. Then iterate over this sequence. This code shows how one might do that

```
def TupleGenerator(row):
    result = []
    for word in row["Song"].strip('"').split():
        result.append((word, row["Points"]))
    return result
```

The `strip` method of strings accepts one optional argument that is a string that specifies the set of characters to be removed. In our case, we need to remove `"`. The `split` method without any arguments returns a list of the words in the string, using consecutive whitespace string subsequences as the delimiter.

For example, if your `df` is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Year": 1957,
     "Date": "3-Mar",
     "Host City": ["Frankfurt", "Linux"],
     "Winner": ["Netherlands", "Unix"],
     "Song": ['"Net als toen"', '"git hub"'],
     "Performer": ["Corry Brokken", "Stack Overflow"],
     "Points": [31, 32],
     "Margin": [14, 15],
     "Runner-up": ["France", "cyberspace"]
    }
)
```

Running

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(TupleGenerator(row))
```

gives output

```
[('Net', 31), ('als', 31), ('toen', 31)]
[('git', 32), ('hub', 32)]
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if there are any questions!